# If a function was entered via a near call, can it do a far tail call without breaking return address prediction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

Consider this code:

```
.globl _non_tail, _tail
.text

.code32
_non_tail:
    lcall $0x33, $_non_tail.heavensgate
    ret

.code64
_non_tail.heavensgate:
    # do stuff. there's 12 bytes on the stack before the first argument
    lret

.code32
_tail:
    pushl (%esp)
    movw %cs, 4(%esp)
    ljmp $0x33, $_tail.heavensgate

.code64
_tail.heavensgate:
    # do stuff. there's 8 bytes on the stack before the first argument
    lret
```

Will `_tail` cause the return stack buffer to mispredict future returns? On the one hand, it's pairing a near call with a far return, but on the other hand, it's still returning to the exact same place that it would have normally.

Comment: You can also do `push cs` \ `call near function` to call a function, in your current `cs`, that returns far. I assume neither case will be easily predicted.

Comment: Will the CPU even speculate past a far call or ret? That's such an edge case (far calls are almost never used, let alone intra-privileged ones like the *heavensgate*, which comes from Malwares) and the Return Address Predictor would also need to remember at least the original bitness for the FE to speculate ahead of the execution of an `lret`. It seems cumbersome, from a quick test I don't see any difference between a `push cs / push ret_label / jmp 33h:func/retf` (not predicated normally) and `call 33h:func / retf` (predicted).

Comment: ^ I tried to adapt the first two columns of [Table 1 of Henry Wong's post about RAP/RAS](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/).

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm not really interested in what happens with the far return itself. I'm interested in what happens with all of the subsequent near returns.

Comment: I suspect this would break future rets in the caller of `_tail`, since there was never a near `ret` to balance the near `call`.  I'm assuming that far ret and far call don't interact with the RAS (return address stack) predictor, as @MargaretBloom suggested.  (As far as real-world usage of far jumps/calls, WOW64 does a far call from 32-bit user-space into 64-bit user-space DLL code at least to execute `syscall` instead of using 32-bit `sysenter`.  Seems inefficient to me, but it's *possible* Intel would have put some engineering effort into predicting that commercially-relevant return.)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ah ok, sorry. I misunderstood you. Anyway, it seems that far calls/rets are ignored by the RAS/RAP. A far call will take 214 cycles on average on my CPU. A near call that contains only a far call or only a push+far_jump will take 218 cycles regardless, which seems consistent with the timing from Henry Wong (~4 cycles per predicted return + 214 cycles per far call/jmp) and I think shows that far rets are ignored (or the near call would be mispredicted).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Since you have experimental results compatible with my guess, that's sufficient to post an answer.  Feel free to quote or paraphrase my comment.  It's not a surprising result, although if you have time to write up how you benchmarked, it might be fun to include that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm too rusty to write an answer :) please go ahead if you feel like so